# UIScrollView with multiple UIImageView shown

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios5, uiimageview, xcode4.2

I'm trying to achieve scroll view with multiple images. I put the UIScrollView and put 3 UIImageView which the last one is out of bounds. I though that i can scroll the content of the srollview component. How could i achieve this. I have just found examples where the scrollView show just one picture at the time. How could i have multiple pictures shown in UIScrollView.

Something like this:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: OK i found method of UIScrollView setContentSize which do what i need. Is there some property which set the size automatically by content?

Comment: kubo, you are correct.  You want to use setContentSize.  There is no functionality to set the size automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the correct method which i was looking for is setContentSize. I thought that there is some setting to do this automatically to the included content. But as Grett writhed there is nothing like that. So i guest this is the only way do that.